# Android ListView Memory Usage

Tags: android, listview, memory

I don't know where the problem is, because of that I came here.

**Instruction:**

I have a ListView where I get the data from Internet.
In the URL, I have a JSON-String, but there isn't the problem. I'm getting the data problem-free from URL and there's also a Image URL, which I'm loading them with Picasso into ListView with other data.

**Going to problem**

I have a navigation with 3 points. Each time when the user press one of them I load the infos from URL belonging to that item (example.php?json=1), so I don't change the page, I just remove the adapter (list.clear) and reload the data.

**Problem**

Each time when I press the SAME item on navigation, the MEMORY gets higher 1mb.

Example the Memory usage is 80mb and when I press the navigation "Example 1" it gets 81mb, and when I press it gets 82mb, etc.

**Code**

*MainActivity.java*

```
private void loadGames(final String title, String pageUrl, final boolean reset) {
    if(reset) resetGames();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, pageUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if(response.length() > 0) {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                RootObject object = gson.fromJson(response, RootObject.class);

                for (int i = 0; i < object.result.size(); i++) {

                    ... BLA BLA BLA

                    articles.add(new ArticleItem(object.result.get(i).id, object.result.get(i).title, (int) days, object.result.get(i).value, object.result.get(i).picURL, object.result.get(i).url, object.result.get(i).promoter, object.result.get(i).description, object.result.get(i).participationDate, participated));
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if(reset) YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceInUp).duration(1500).playOn(articleView);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    actionBar.setPageTitle(title);
}
```

**Edit**

*ArticleAdapter.java*

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArticleItem> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ArticleItem> articles;

    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, List<ArticleItem> articles) {
        super(context, 0, articles);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_layout, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle());

        TextView days = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.days);

        TextView desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        desc.setText("Promoter: " + articles.get(position).getPromoter());

        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.ablaufzeit_weiss).into((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.letzte_chance_icon));
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.gesamtwert_weiss).into((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.geld_icon));

        int amount = articles.get(position).getDays();
        String tage = (amount > 1) ? "Days" : "Day";
        days.setText("In " + amount + " " + tage);
        if(amount == 0)
            days.setText("Ends today");
        else if(amount < 0)
            days.setText("End");

        TextView worth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.worth);
        worth.setText(articles.get(position).getWorth() + " €");

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(articles.get(position).getImgUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(image);

        ViewGroup articleInfo = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.article_info);
        articleInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='black'>" + articles.get(position).getTitle() + "</font>"));
                builder.setMessage(articles.get(position).getDesc())
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });

        if(articles.get(position).isParticipated()) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.participated).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView participatedText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.participated_text);
            participatedText.setTypeface(FontCache.get("Action_Man.ttf", getContext()));
            participatedText.setText("Participated\nam " + articles.get(position).getParticipationDate());
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.participated).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

resetGames()

```
private void resetGames() {
    articles.clear();
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Post the adapter code

Comment: post the adapter code. It might be a issue with your list.you should consider trying list.clear() before adding new datas.

Comment: Done, the adapter code is there now.

Comment: where articles variable is declared in your code? Is it reset each time you press navigation?

Comment: articles is a List variable, where I use it for custom adapter to add different views (it also works) is declared in MainActivity. As you can see it gets reset below loadGames function. The resetGames() code is added.

Comment: somewhere it's adding duplicated results or previous result on navigation change. Use logcat and check the size change of both list array and adapter array on change of navigation.

Comment: I checked the size of articles variable and adapter array, they always show  the correct value. So, when I change navigation, the ListView contains example 5 views and the logcat shows the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one quene for application

Every time you call loadGames() you create new instance

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Create Quene manager

```
public class QueueManager {

private static final String TAG = QueueManager.class.getName();
private static QueueManager queueManager;
private Context ctx;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

private QueueManager(Context context) {
    ctx = context.getApplicationContext();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized QueueManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (queueManager == null) {
        queueManager = new QueueManager(context);
    }
    return queueManager;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    return requestQueue;
}
```

in activity you can access

`quene = QueueManager.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();`

Comment: I changed it, thanks, but why is it not good to do like I did. Where's the different?

Comment: Creating quene is heavy operation. You should make it only one time. Each quene allocate resources.

Comment: In my script I everywhere create a new instance, this makes my app slower? Please help me how I should work. I have a created a class for Navigation menü and I need it only one time, so I call new Nav() only once. The question is, is that worth to make it in Class or should I move them to Activity?